# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: python, api, unicode, buffer, typeerror

I have 2 APIs. I am fetching data from them. I want to assign particular code parts to string so that life became easier while coding. Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
import json

urlIncomeStatement = 'http://dev.c0l.in:8888'
apiIncomeStatement = urllib2.urlopen(urlIncomeStatement)
dataIncomeStatement = json.load(apiIncomeStatement)

urlFinancialPosition = 'http://dev.c0l.in:9999'
apiFinancialPosition = urllib2.urlopen(urlFinancialPosition)
dataFinancialPositiont = json.load(apiFinancialPosition)

for item in dataIncomeStatement:
    name = item['company']['name']
    interestPayable = int(item['company']['interest_payable'])
    interestReceivable = int(item['company']['interest_receivable'])
    sales = int(item['company']['interest_receivable'])
    expenses = int(item['company']['expenses'])
    openingStock = int(item['company']['opening_stock'])
    closingStock = int(item['company']['closing_stock'])
    sum1 = sales + expenses

    if item['sector'] == 'technology':
        name + "'s interest payable - " + interestPayable
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + interestReceivable
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + sales
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + expenses
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + openingStock
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + closingStock

print sum1
```

In result I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gnite_000/Desktop/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    name + "'s interest payable - " + interestPayable
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback?

Comment: Sure: `
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gnite_000/Desktop/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    name + "'s interest payable - " + interestPayable
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
`

Comment: Why do you do all these `name + 's interest receivable - ' +` statements? They get thrown away in your current code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem might have to do with the fact that you are adding ints to strings here

```
    if item['sector'] == 'technology':
        name + "'s interest payable - " + interestPayable
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + interestReceivable
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + sales
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + expenses
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + openingStock
        name + "'s interest receivable - " + closingStock
```

As far as I'm aware, the interpretor cannot implicitly convert an int to a string.
This might work, though,

```
       str(name) + "'s interest receivable - " + str(closingStock)
```

On which I'm assuming Python > 3.0

Comment: If I would remove int(), I would get same error, but instead of in found, I would get float found

Comment: @MarksGniteckis yes, because in the serialized object, the data you are pointing to is a float, not a string. You convert it to an int, then add to a string. Neither float nor int can be added to string. Just wrap them in str(), like `+ str(interestPayable)`.

Comment: Okay, added a different solution to the problem. Which selllikesybok was talking about.

Comment: "As far as I'm aware, the interpretor cannot implicitly convert an int to a string" : it's not a limitation, it's by design.

Comment: Also the right solution is to use string formatting (cf the fine Python manual for your Python version).

Comment: Python 2.7 - this seems more convincing way for some. 
Wrap everything between quote and replace variable with %s

`" %s 's interest receivable - %s"%(name, closingStock)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add '%s' % and () to each line, like this:

```
'%s' % (name + "'s interest payable - " + interestPayable)
```

Comment: Try this. Python 2.7 - this seems more convincing way for some. 
Wrap everything between quote and replace variable with %s

`" %s 's interest receivable - %s"%(name, closingStock)`

Comment: This answer will result in the same coersion. It should be changed to something like "%s's interest receivable - %s" % (name, interestPayable) as suggested in the comments by @ajaykools.